# How can i get this SQL on yii2?

Tags: yii2

I am working with Yii2 and I need to use the Query Builder to convert the following raw SQL query where I am using a subquery in the inner join.

```
SELECT *
FROM class
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT name, MAX(score) AS Maxscore
    FROM class
    GROUP BY name) topscore 
ON class.name = topscore.name 
AND class.score = topscore.maxscore;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should show a bit of effort on your behalf as it is how it works here on SO, but as you are a new bee so i am adding an answer.

It is pretty straight forward see the Query builder [guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder), and you need to use the subquery in the following way

```
$subQuery = new \yii\db\Query();
$subQuery->select([new \yii\db\Expression('[[name]], MAX([[score]]) as Maxscore')])
    ->from('class')
    ->groupBy('[[name]]');

$query = new \yii\db\Query();
$query->select('*')
    ->from('class')
    ->innerJoin(['topscore'=>$subQuery])
    ->where(['=','class.[[name]]',new \yii\db\Expression('topscore.[[name]]')])
    ->andWhere(['=','class.[[score]]',new \yii\db\Expression('topscore.[[maxscore]]')])
    ->all();
```

Note: I didn't tested it thou but it should work correctly.